# Rails: How to setup multiple relation types to same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a `Product` and `Category` model which have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation.
So I can search for `Product.categories` or `Category.products`

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Now I wanna add a new relation to the `Product`:
It should called `main_category` which only should be a `has_one` relation from the `Product` to the `Category`. So a `Product` only can have one MainCategory. But the Category of course should return all MainCategory products.

- Must I create a SubClass of Category? Normally I would like to not create an extra class
- How can I solve that to simply call `Product.main_category` or `Category.main_products`?
- How to place indexes properly?
- How does the migration should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it like this i guess

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
     has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
     belongs_to :main_category, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :main_category_id
end
```

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
     has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
     has_many :main_products, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: :main_category_id
end
```

You will have to add an column to `products` table called `main_category_id`

Source https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations